# Autolauncher misselected in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

You know that popup that shows up if you connect a USB device that has files on it? I once accidently selected WIndoes Media pLayer for my galaxy III and know everytime i charge it up that thing opens up...how can i change the setting to do nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the settings through `AutoPlay`.  Open the Control Panel and type `autoplay` in the search box in the upper right corner.  Open the `AutoPlay` applet and select the default action you want.